# Comment indexer alphabétiquement les mots commençant par une lettre accentuée ?

Tags: alphabet, diacritiques

Lorsque l'on donne un index alphabétique, où doivent être placés les mots commençant par un accent ?

Par exemple, où classé-je *établi* et *à-coup* ? Après tous les mots commençant respectivement par E et A, ou au milieu (comme si l'accent n'était pas là) ? De même, pour les mots en œ.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Le tri se fait comme suit:

- une passe en ignorant les différences entre majuscules et minuscules et les signes diacritiques et les caractères autres que les lettres;
- les égalités sont résolues en tenant compte des signes diacritiques, la lettre non accentuée venant en particulier toujours en premier; c'est la dernière lettre ayant une différence qui est la plus significative (donc *cote*, *côte*, *coté*, *côté*);
- les égalités sont résolues en tenant compte de la différence de casse (les majuscules suivent les minuscules), dans l'ordre normal;
- les égalités sont résolues en distinguant *æ* de *ae* et *œ* de *oe* (aux étapes précédentes, ils sont classés identiquement);
- les égalités sont résolues en tenant compte des autres caractères (signes de ponctuation);
- les égalités restantes sont résolues de manière arbitraire.

Voir [ce document](http://www-clips.imag.fr/geta/gilles.serasset/tri-du-francais.html). Il est sorti une norme ISO (14651) de ce travail d'analyse de ce que faisait les différents dictionnaires.

Comment: réponse très intéressante, merci

Comment: Est-ce que les points 4 et 6 correspondent à de réels cas ?

Comment: @Benoit, 4 peut arriver avec des fautes d'orthographes ou de saisie. A priori, 6 doit résulter de considération plus purement informatique (deux manières de coder un même caractère par exemple).

Answer (score 1):

D'après l'article du [classement alphabétique](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classement_alphab%C3%A9tique#Exemples) sur Wikipédia :

> Si plusieurs mots ont le même rang alphabétique, on tâche de les distinguer entre eux grâce aux majuscules et aux accents. Exemple: légitime, légitimé, légitimes, légitimés.

Il semble que le mot avec un accent soit classé après celui sans accent.

Answer (score 0):

Je n'ai pas de preuve à l'appui mais j'ai toujours vu les indexations comme si l'accent n'y était pas (par exemple dans le dictionnaire juste à côté de moi, c'est le cas).

Comment: … jusqu'aux termes que l'accent départage. Comment est-ce que ce dictionnaire range les différents « cote », sinon ?